# Using java to input SQL Query with backslash

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a java program which connects to a database in Oracle SQL Developer.
I need data from the database to export to a .csv file. I can do this directly in SQL Developer using spooling as shown

```
spool D:\fileLocation\fileName.csv
select /*csv*/ * from Table;
spool off
```

I need to be able to input that to SQL Developer FROM the java program. I can input a query from java to sql using code below

```
Statement SumLevel = connection.createStatement();
    try{
        SumLevel.executeQuery("SQL Query");
        System.out.println("Succesfuly Entered Data");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        if(CompareLevel != null){
            CompareLevel.close();
        }
    }
```

Obviously the \ in java is not just a character so if I try the first line of the spooling in java it will try to do \f  which is a separate function.

Using \\ prints out the desired code but when it inputs into sql it says there is an error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement". 
I believe this is due to SQL reading the code showing \\ rather than \

```
spool D:\\fileLocatoin\\fileName.csv
select /*csv*/ * from Table;
spool off
```

How would I be able to input the sql spooling code into a java program.

Thanks

Comment: You don't.  You use java code to write the file from the query results, after you run the query.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **You can't** run `spool` command from `Java`.

Explanation.

Java is not connects to `Oracle SQL Developer` it connects to Oracle database.
Oracle database can run `SQL` queries.

`spool` command is not part of `SQL`. It  is command of `Oracle SQL Developer` command language.

**Solution**

Either you run your `SQL` query (`select * from Table`, note that it doesn't allow comment in it) and then process result and write to file using some `CSV` lib.

Or you continue to use `Oracle SQL Developer` tool.